# How to make the strings have the same content?

Tags: c, for-loop, char, printf, esp32

I have two strings and I am using `sprintf` in both cases to pass from one format to another from an array or string but in one of the cases it does it well and in the other it does not.

```
    char string1[32];
    char string1[32];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(string1); i++)
    {
        sprintf(string1 + (i * 2), "%02x", bytesesp[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(string1); i++)
    {
        sprintf(string2 + (i * 2), "%02x", bytesesp1[i]);
    }
```

Where `bytesesp` and `bytesesp1` both contain the following

```
20d56f5dae4ee2638db37e4b25d78bbbc42338edee4e4baed8fca4bde1d113b1
```

In my case I get the following

```
String 4 :20d56f5dae4ee2638db37e4b25d78bbbc42338edee4e4baed8fca4bde1d113b1
String5 :��������������������������������20d56f5dae4ee2638db37e4b25d78bbbc42338edee4e4baed8fca4bde1d113b1
```

How can I solve this, bearing in mind that I work on an esp32.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates your observations. The shown code is even unlikely to be compileable if inserted in a suitable code context.

Comment: Your example has two definitions of `string1`, and is missing a proper definition of `bytesesp` and `bytesesp1`. Please make sure to precisely copy your [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to the question. Note that `sizeof(string1)` is used in *both* conditions. Please try to clarify your example.

Comment: How many characters are in `20d56f5dae4ee2638db37e4b25d78bbbc42338edee4e4baed8fca4bde1d113b1`???  And please post your **actual** code - your posted code has two identical `char string1[32];` declarations.  What **else** is wrongly copied?

Comment: The code try to fill 64 char in array of 32 char! The result is totally undefined for both strings.

Comment: @dalfaB 65 counting the terminating `'\0'` character... ;-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle, you're right.

Comment: Your boundaries are off; should be `(sizeof string - 1) / 2`. (The answer uses odd numbers, which are also valid, they are truncated.)

Answer (score 1):

The function `sprintf` builds a string in the character array supplied as the first argument. That is it appends terminating zero character `'\0'`.

From the description of the function `sprintf` in the C Standard (7.21.6.6 The sprintf function)

> 2 The sprintf function is equivalent to fprintf, except that the
> output is written into an array (specified by the argument s) rather
> than to a stream. **A null character is written at the end of the
> characters written**; it is not counted as part of the returned value.
> If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is
> undefined.

For example if you have an array like this:

```
char string1[2];
```

then this call:

```
sprintf(string1, "%02x", 1 );
```

will write the terminating zero character `'\0'` outside the array `string1` that results in undefined behavior.

So at least your arrays should have odd values of sizes.

Another problem is an invalid condition in the for loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(string1); i++)
```

You should write for example:

```
for ( size_t i = 0, n = sizeof( string1 ); i < n / 2; i++)
```

Otherwise in your original for loops for example for `i` equal to `31` this expression `string1+ (i * 2)` equal to `string1+ 62` points far away from the array `string1`.

Comment: even with `i < n / 2` there will be a buffer overflow for the last null terminator